# How to finish the soundpool as soon as I close the activity?

Tags: android, soundpool

If I start sound playback and immediately hit the back button and close that activity, the sound-pool completes the sound. How can I finish the sound-pool as soon as I hit the back button?

Comment: Check for the `BACK` button press and call `stop()` on the `SoundPool` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this on your code,

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
 super.onBackPressed();
 soundpoolobject.stop();
```

}